# Openlayers package 3.15.1 on build it generates ol.js minified file with v5.3.0

Tags: node.js, npm, build, version, openlayers-3

I have downloaded Openlayers 3.15.1 package from link https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/tree/v3.15.1.

After i install NPM & Nodejs and run a build it generates ol.js minified as well as ol-debug.js file with v5.3.0

Existing version of ol.js in my project

```
// OpenLayers 3. See http://openlayers.org/
// License: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/ol3/master/LICENSE.md
// Version: v3.15.1
```

With my downloaded package build i get

```
// OpenLayers 3. See http://openlayers.org/
// License: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/ol3/master/LICENSE.md
// Version: v5.3.0-828-gad5c9ac58
```

I expect the same version to be built from my package. Not sure why this version differ occurs.

Comment: Please provide a minimum example that reproduces the problem. Especially give info about how you run a build and your build configuration (package.json etc)

Comment: The actual problem is i need to checkout a particular version say v3.15.1 from github. Pls provide with the steps

Comment: Again... please provide a minimum example that demonstrates the problem. Nobody actually knows what your project structure, package.json, build config etc look like. If you download/clone the source code from Github you'll have to build OL first. How that is done is described in their readme. Did you try the distribution zip from https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v3.15.1 ?